# Theos not creating header files when compiling library

Tags: ios, objective-c, dylib, theos

I am trying to make a simple library to to use in my application.

After compiling, all I see in my cydia package is a .dylib, but not any header folder which contains the library headers?

How do I make theos to compile the dylib with headers?
I am using the library nic that comes with theos after installing it

Comment: Did you create project as a static library?

Comment: I used a template that compiles my source code as a dylib